# $query->result() returning empty array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter active records for some time now and this is the most ridiculous error I've got.

My query is

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->where('is_active', 1);

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    //return $query->result();
    return $query;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

---

when I use`$query->result();` It is empty. When I use `return $query;`
the result is like below,

```
CI_DB_pdo_result Object
(
    [num_rows] => 21
    [conn_id] => PDO Object
        (
        )

    [result_id] => PDOStatement Object
        (
            [queryString] => SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE is_active =  1
        )

    [result_array] => Array
        (
        )

    [result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [custom_result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [current_row] => 0
    [row_data] => 
)
```

---

Count is

> [num_rows] => 21

what is missing/problem here?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. This thing happens because my application use PDO DB Driver. Not MySQL Driver.

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
```

So I changed my model to support that.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  my_table WHERE is_active = 1";
$stmt1 = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
$stmt1->execute();
return $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now it's working fine.

> I am really sorry for your time people. And thank you very much for
>   trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->where('is_active', 1);

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();

if (count($result) > 0) {
    return $result;
} 
else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

> You're not formatting the query array. So format it.

Answer (score 0):

simple add
    $query = $this->db->get()->result(); 
  in your code

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->where('is_active', 1);

$query = $this->db->get()->result();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
//return $query->result();
      return $query;
} else {
return FALSE;
```

}

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->where('is_active', 1);
return $this->db->get()->result();

try this

Answer (score 0):

`if ($query->num_rows() > 0)` then return `$query->result()` which returns results in `object` format.Like this..

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result();
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Then use `arrow(->)` operator to retrieved required values.
For more see here [Codeigniter Result Formats](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Comment: Tried. But same result. Returns and empty array.

Comment: what is output on `print_r($query->result_array())`?

Comment: print an empty array. `Array
(
)`

Comment: I have edited it try using arrow operator like `$returned_array->column_name;`

Answer (score 0):

If u want to get result you must use row() or result() function.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->where('is_active', 1);

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    //return $query->result();
   return $this->db->get()->result();
    //return $query;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->where('is_active', 1);

$query = $this->db->get();

$i = 0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $i++;
    $data['id'] = $row->id;
    $data['username'] = $row->username;
}


if ($i > 0) {
    return $data;
}
```